# SQL Server pivot calculate and convert row into column

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a temp table that is being created by joining 3-4 tables.The result is as below.

```
NAME                                EMP_ID     CODE Status  Department
----------------------------------------------------------------------
SHARIFAH SURAYA BINTI BAHARUDIN     30100359    A   IN      ENG
FATIN NADIA BINTI MOHAMMAD          30100360    B   IN      ENG
NOOR AZIAH BINTI MOHD NOOR          30100361    A   Absent  ENG
NURUL ATIKA BINTI ALI ASAN          30100363    A   Absent  PACK
SITI UMI KALSOM BINTI AMRAN         30100364    B   Absent  PACK
ZAINATUL NABILA BINTI ZAINUDIN      30100365    A   Absent  PACK
MOHD ZARUL BIN ZAUKAFLI             30100367    A   IN      COM
AIREEN SYAFIRA BINTI JAMALUDIN      30100369    A   IN      COM
FARAH WAHIDA BINTI MOHD ISA         30100371    C   IN      PACK
MUHAMAD FAIZAL BIN AZMAN            30100259    A   IN      COM
SITI NOOR HAFIZAH BINTI ZAKARANI    30100264    A   IN      PACK
NUR FATEHAH BINTI MISTAM            30100277    Z   IN      PACK
```

I would like it to come out as a pivot table, like this:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add the sample data in text format instead of image

Comment: @Prdp thx for the respond..edited

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: @Prdp version 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using conditional aggregate

```
SELECT department,
       Concat(Count(CASE WHEN code = 'a' AND status = 'IN' THEN 1 END), '/', Count(CASE WHEN code = 'a' THEN 1 END)),
       Concat(Count(CASE WHEN code = 'b' AND status = 'IN' THEN 1 END), '/', Count(CASE WHEN code = 'b' THEN 1 END)),
       Concat(Count(CASE WHEN code = 'c' AND status = 'IN' THEN 1 END), '/', Count(CASE WHEN code = 'c' THEN 1 END)),
       Concat(Count(CASE WHEN code = 'z' AND status = 'IN' THEN 1 END), '/', Count(CASE WHEN code = 'z' THEN 1 END))
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY department
```

If the values in code column is unknown then use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT department,'

SET @SQL += (SELECT DISTINCT Concat('Count(CASE WHEN code = ''', code, ''' AND status = ''IN'' THEN 1 END)', '/', 'Count(CASE WHEN code = ''', code, ''' THEN 1 END),')
             FROM   YOURTABLE
             FOR XML PATH(''))
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, Len(@SQL) - 1)
SET @SQL += 'FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY department '

--SELECT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```